# How to listen to the changes and rebuild the widget in flutter using provider packge?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

The problem i am facing is,
I am connecting my ui to backend with websocket using subscribe method(graphql client). That means there is a connection between my ui and backend. I am storing the data i got from backend  in the local storage
From the local storage, i am getting that data,

Whenever i receive the data from backend it should be reflected in the ui automatically. For reflecting change in ui, i am using state management provider package.What should i do to make my widget rebuild on listening to the changes i had made using provider package;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
   bool _listenableValue = false;
   bool get listenableValue => _listenableValue

   MyNotifier.instance();

   void setValue(){
      _listenableValue = !_listenableValue;
      notifyListeners();
   }
}


...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyNotifier>(
       create: (context) => MyNotifier.instance(),
       builder: (context, child){
          return Column(
             children: [
                StaticWidget(),
                //This text widget will rebuild when value is changed
                Selector<MyNotifier, bool>(
                  selector: (_, notifier) => notifier.listenableValue,
                  builder: (_, value, __) => Text('$value');
                ),
                //Change value with button
                IconButton(
                  icon: //icon
                  onPressed: (){
                    context.read<MyNotifier>().setValue();
                  },
                );
             ]
          );
       }
   );
}
```

Don' t use `Consumer`. Consumer will rebuild all widgets when a data changed. This is the bad situation for performance.
`Selector` is the best in my opinion.

Comment: It depends where you put the `Consumer`, actually. Please track the rebuild widgets both way and see the difference by changing `useConsumer` variable and restarting the app: gist.github.com/nesimtunc/bfed1de47d46245f252051c4343c9e94 As Provider document recommends to put Consumer in the deepest widget, will reduce the unnecessary rebuilding.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your state in a ChangeNotifier like:

```
class MyState extends ChangeNotifier{
addStorage(Map<String, String> data) {...}
getAllDataFromStorage() {...}
}
```

Then you can make your UI rebuild by just wrapping the desired widgets in a `Consumer`.

```
Consumer<MyState>(builder: (context, state) {
return Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
           child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
             if (screenLayout >= 1024) {
               return desktopWidget(context, visitsList);
             } else if (screenLayout >= 768 && screenLayout <= 1023) {
               return tabletWidget(context, visitsList);
             } else {
               return mobileWidget(context, visitingsList, screenLayout);
             }
           })},
         );
```

Note that somewhere above this snippet you should have a `ChangeNotifierProvider` injecting your `MyState` in the widget tree.
For a really thorough and complete guide take a look at [Simple state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#lifting-state-up)

Comment: It's throwing exception. setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build

Answer (score 1):

```
**best way to listen changes in provider its to make getter and setter i will show you example below**
 class ContactProvider with ChangeNotifier {
     bool isBusy = true;
    bool get IsBusy => isBusy;
    set IsBusy(bool data) {
        this.isBusy = data;
        notifyListeners();
      }
void maketru(){
IsBusy=false;
}
}
```

and now you can use this `context.read<ContactProvider>().Isbusy;`

Comment: ok Muhammad Arbaz Zafar ,this is helpful.